# create truth table in php (AND / OR)

Tags: php

i have an array contain value like

```
Array
(
    [0] = true
    [1] = OR
    [2] = true
    [3] = AND
    [4] = false
    [5] = AND
    [6] = true
)
```

i want to create truth table in php like e.g

```
true OR true = result1
result1 AND false = result2
result2 AND true = result3
```

i'm stupid and not b able to create yet. :(

here is my code

```
foreach( $arrValue as $val  )
{
     if(!empty($val))
     {
    if($val=='true')
        $p = true;
    elseif($val=='false')
        $p = false;

    if(isset($p))
    {
            if(isset($result))
        {
             if($val=='AND')
             $result = $result AND $p;                      
        elseif($val=='OR')
             $$result = $result or $p;              

        }
       else
        $result = $p;
    }           
    }
}
```

please help this stupid boy to get results.

Comment: Im sure bit masks would be a better solution to this !

Comment: @saint: Do you mean a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map? Please elaborate your question!?

Comment: @epitaph: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table - Ignore the bitmasks comments, thought we was talking about something else

Comment: @Robert: I didn't know that a Truth-Table can be build with binary code. Did it help to find a race condition or a minterm? What is saint purpose to make a truth-table?

Comment: @epitaph: I'm making a process that automatically generated some results and store in db. in the process results are joined with each other with some AND / OR condition to describe the best solution. 
i stored all the results in array with operator as i shown in array above. there are multiple decision. to reach at single decision i joined the results and apply truth table.

Comment: @saint: Do you want to find a matching of answers/attributes? Isn't that a question for graph-theory? For example a Floyd-Warhshall algorithm? I'm a bit confused!

Comment: @epitaph: No. 
Array ( [0] => true [1] => OR [2] => true [3] => AND [4] => false [5] => AND [6] => true ); 
This is array contain the results of each processes. e.g: process 1 successfully processed and return true and store at location 0. then i hv operator OR to join with 2nd Process who result also true and i stor @ location 2 in array. similarly the processes execute and there results in ( true / false ) store in array with relevant Operator (OR / AND) . At the end i got array as above.

Comment: @saint: Why don't you split the array in 2 arrays and use a matrix? Or you can use 2 loops? Your array is always of even elements?

Comment: Hope my code ll help u how i make array..

while($data = mysql_fetch_array($results))
{
        $status = getStatus($data['processNo']);  
 array_push($variables,$status);
 array_push($variables,$data['row_operator']);
}

getStatus($process)
{
     //...............
     return true/false;
}

Comment: @epitaph:
i'm trying this:
function row_operator1($arrValue)
{ 
 $i=-2; $j=-1;
 foreach( $arrValue as $val  )
 {  
  if($i+3 > count($arrValue)) break;
  $boolste = boolstr($arrValue[$i+2]);
  if(isset($res))
  {
   if($arrValue[$j+2]=='AND')
   {
   $res = $res and $boolste;       
  }
   elseif($arrValue[$j+2]=='OR')
   {

    $res = $res | $boolste;

   }
    
    $j += 2;       
  }
  else
   $res = $boolste;  
   
  $i += 2;
 }
 return $res;
 //var_dump($result);
}
function boolstr($val) {
   return ($val) ? 'true' : 'false';
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is what i want.

```
//( [0] => true [1] => OR [2] => true [3] => AND [4] => false [5] => AND [6] => true)

function boolstr($val) {
    if($val=='true')
        return true;
    elseif($val=='false')
        return false;
}


function row_operator($arrValue){
    $i=-2; $j=-1;
    foreach( $arrValue as $val  )
    {
        if($i+3 > count($arrValue)) break;
        $boolste = boolstr($arrValue[$i+2]);
        if(isset($res))
        {
            if($arrValue[$j+2]=='AND')
                $res = $res && $boolste;
            elseif($arrValue[$j+2]=='OR')           
                $res = $res || $boolste;            

            if($res==true)
                $a='true';
            else $a= 'false';
                $j += 2;
        }
        else
            $res = $boolste;

        $i += 2;
    }
    return $res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

have you thought about creating a truth table with callbacks, for example:

```
$table = array();

$table[] = array(
    'name' => 'equals',
    'call' => 'check_equals'
);

$table[] = array(
    'name' => 'or',
    'call' => 'check_or'
);

$myData = array(
    true => true,
    false => true,
    true => false,
    true => -1,
)


foreach($myData as $first => $second)
{
     foreach($table as $check)
     {
         echo $check['name'] . call_user_func($check['call'],$first,$second) ? 'good' : 'bad';
     }
}
```

adn then just create your callbacks like so:

```
function check_or($f1,$f2)
{
    return $f1 || $f2;
}

function check_equals($f1,$f2)
{
    return $f1 === $f2;
}
```